# Jquery Ajax Call - Error with Callback Function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

So i'm trying to do this ajax request with jquery (coffeescript) but i'm having problems with the callback function, it tells me that "data" is undefined, but sometimes, when I re-write the code, it doesn't give me a console error and instead does nothing. I know the request goes through because rails handles the request fine, but there may be an issue sending back information, so i'll include my controller code as well. Thanks a bunch for the help.

```
submit_yes = ->
par = $(this).parent().parent()
event_id = par.find('#event_id').val()
time_module_id = par.find('#time_module_id').val()
$.ajax
  type: "PUT",
  url: '/events/'+event_id+'/add_yes_rsvp?' + par.find('#time_module_id').serialize(),
  data: JSON.stringify({ _method:'put' })
  success: (data) ->
    alert data
    update_score(par.parent())
return true

def add_yes_rsvp
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  TimeModule.find(params[:time_module_id]).add_yes_rsvp(current_user)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render json: { error: false }}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The available formats and content type requested don't match. You basically have three options:

1. Set the request header content type using the "accepts" setting for $.ajax to "json"
2. Add .json to the end of the url you're requesting
3. Change format.json to format.js

Comment: Turned out to be indentation issues, but these also made the code more robust.